# Rashi's Six Question types

Tags: rashi, pentateuch-chumash

I heard (possibly in the name of the Beer Mayim Chaim) that all of Rashi's commentary al hatorah addresses one of six questions: קושי בדקדוק, סמיכת הענינים, לשון מיותר, סתירה, שינוי בלשון, קושי הבנה

I also found this on [chinuch.org](http://www.chinuch.org/item_detail/5/106/Rashi-Questions-Chart-)

Does anyone have a reliable source for this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I assume someone just figured this covered all the bases. Sometimes Rashi deals with changes in spelling that don't directly relate to dikduk problems, though. So not an exhaustive list.